# change array into table bash scripting

Tags: bash

how to change array into tabular form?

eg:

```
array = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

result

```
 1 10 11
 2 9  12
 3 8  
 4 7
 5 6
```

in this particular order up-down-down-up-up-down

the array is taken from a .txt file and its based on user input so the value varies

here is some of my code

```
declare -a myarray
# Load file into array.
readarray myarray < temp2.txt
s=$myarray
f  or i in $(seq 0 $((${#s} - 1))); do
        echo "s[$i] = \"${s:$i:1}\""
done
```

Comment: If the array is of size N, how many rows and columns do you expect in the output?

Comment: depends, but each column must have 5 element in it, that mean 5 rows just like the table in my earlier post

Comment: Your code sample doesn't seem to be an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: What does _up-down-down-up-up-down_ mean?

Comment: @TomFenech It means, I believe, that the output snakes around the columns as opposed to simply being split along columns printing downwards.

Comment: @Etan yeah I though that as well but the example would be "down-up-down" wouldn't it?

Comment: @thatotherguy i tried using for loop to print out 5 arrays but its doesnt make sense and giving out errors. im basically blank over here

Comment: @TomFenech I agree but I think he is indicating line endpoints (think stroke positions) as opposed to columnar order. And yes, that is confusing and bizarre.

Comment: @SharfudinMohdIbrahim That loop isn't operating over an array. It is operating over a string. The first element of the array `myarray`. `$myarray` is equivalent to `${myarray[0]}`.

Comment: @TomFenech my bad. i mean from up towards down, down towards up. im sorry for my bad english, as english is not my mother languange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script does what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 )
rows=5

for (( j=0; j<rows; ++j )); do 
    for (( i=0; i<=$(( ${#a[@]} / rows )); ++i )); do        
        if (( i%2 )); then idx=$(( (i + 1) / 2 * 2 * rows - j - 1 ))
        else idx=$(( (i / 2) * 2 * rows + j )); fi
        printf "%-4s" "${a[idx]}"
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

Output:

```
1   10  11      
2   9   12      
3   8   13  18  
4   7   14  17  
5   6   15  16
```

To make it work from left to right rather than from top to bottom, you can simply swap the `i` and `j` loops around (and change the name `rows` to `cols` so that it still makes sense):

```
#!/bin/bash

a=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 )
cols=5

for (( i=0; i<=$(( ${#a[@]} / cols )); ++i )); do        
    for (( j=0; j<cols; ++j )); do 
        if (( i%2 )); then idx=$(( (i + 1) / 2 * 2 * cols - j - 1 ))
        else idx=$(( (i / 2) * 2 * cols + j )); fi
        printf "%-4s" "${a[idx]}"
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   
10  9   8   7   6   
11  12  13  14  15  
        18  17  16
```

Comment: hi. let say i wanted to use same concept but instead of column, i wanted to use in row. so it will be like in 1st row, left to right. 2nd row right to left. so it will be like (1st row)1 2 3 4 5 (2nd row)10 9 8 7 6

Comment: No problem. Swap the `i` and `j` loops around to make it go horizontally instead. I've updated the answer.

Comment: HOLY IT WORKED! thanks a lot mr Tom. I really appreciate your help. +rep

Comment: btw another quick question. can i save the output in one string by column order (eg. 1 10 11 12 9 2 3 8 13 .....) ?

Comment: I have already answered your original question. I would suggest that you try to change it yourself and if you have any problems, post a new question showing what you've tried and explaining the problem you're having.

Comment: yea thats what im thinking. anyway thanks for your help. i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare -a s
s=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)

ofstabled=(9 7 5 3 1)
ofstableu=(1 3 5 7 9)
for ((i=0; i<5;++i)); do
    for ((j=$i; j<${#s[@]};)); do
        printf "%d " ${s[$j]}
    let j=$j+${ofstabled[$i]}
    if [ $j -lt ${#s[@]} ]; then
        printf "%d " ${s[$j]}
        let j=$j+${ofstableu[$i]}
    fi
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

You can gussy it up if you want but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18)
rows=${1:-5}

col=()
for ((i = 0; i < ${#a[@]}; i++)); do
    ((ind=i % rows))
    (( ((i / rows) % 2 == 0) && (ind = ((rows - 1) - ind)) ))
    [ -n "${col[(rows - 1) - $ind]}" ] && col[(rows - 1) - $ind]+=" "
    col[(rows - 1) - $ind]+=${a[$i]}
done

printf %s\\n "${col[@]}" | column -t
```

Output:

```
$ ./order.sh
1  10  11
2  9   12
3  8   13  18
4  7   14  17
5  6   15  16

$ ./order.sh 3
1  6  7  12  13  18
2  5  8  11  14  17
3  4  9  10  15  16
```

With credit to @TomFenech for the inspiration to make the row count controllable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to read from the file and print it the way you want:

```
$ awk '{
    if(NR<=5) {
        a[NR]=$0
        next
    } else {
        row=NR%10
    }
}
!(row in a) {
    if(row == 0)
        row++
    else
        row=5 - (NR % 5) + 1
}
{
    a[row]=a[row] FS $0
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print a[i]
}' file
1 10 11
2 9 12
3 8
4 7
5 6
```

Comment: hi. let say if i wanted to use the same concept in row instead of column. that is its the same snake like sorting, but from left to right in 1st row, right to left in 2nd row, left to right in 3rd row and so on. and the no of rows is based on user input(ill figure this out later)